# Android multi-button widget: pressing Android Home brakes widget buttons identification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-homebutton

I have a simple widget with 2 buttons. Clicking on any widget button should open the same activity, but **with a different parameter**. Everything works good: clicking button 1 opens an activity and passes param 1, clicking button 2 opens an activity and passes param 2. I check the parameter passed with:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("mode")
```

The problem begins when I press Android **Home** button to close the app - after that the app flow doesn't recognize what button was pressed. But if I close the app with Back button - everything is good.

My guess is that after pressing Home and clicking one of the widget buttons, **the most recent** intent is used instead of using the intent that corresponds to the button clicked.

What I've tried so far:

1. Tried to add actions to intents via intent.setAction()
2. Tried all the possible flags instead of FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
3. Tried activity launch modes: single top and single task. Single task has other problems so I stick with single top.

Here's onUpdate code:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_home);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent1.putExtra("mode", "1");
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent2.putExtra("mode", "2");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
            intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent1);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent2);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.testwidgetbuttons.HomeWidgetProvider"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Example Widget" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget" />
</receiver>
```

Widget xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_home"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:minWidth="146dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

Please advise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your activity is still running when you press the home button, the intent to launch MainActivity is isn't being read through your activity's `onCreate()` method.

[As described here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), when passing a new intent into an existing activity instance, instead use [`Activity.onNewIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29).

If you'd instead like to have any previous instance be finished and recreated, you may want to specify the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP launch flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) into your intents.

Comment: Paul, your two points didn't work separately, but updating both of them (onNewIntent and flag clear top) did the work. Thank you very much.